# Iterate java heap to count java objects within different class loader with following references

Tags: java, jvmti

how to iterate java heap to count java objects within different class loader , and they have following references with each other. For example, X class loader loads 3 class with 3 objects, and these 3 objects have a reference to another 2 objects, and these 2 objects are loaded by Y class loader.
Calc result is count(x->y) = 2

search the stackoverflow

Comment: I'd be somewhat surprised if this was possible.

Comment: This should be possible using the [`FollowReferences`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jvmti.html#FollowReferences) JVMTI function - it reports all references include the references from objects to its classes and the references from classes to class loaders. Just apply the correct filters to the reported objects...